# How to track how many bytes of data your downloading in Python?

Tags: python

So I'm working on a project that requires me to download a bunch of pictures from the internet and then print out how many bytes I've downloaded. I've created a folder to hold all the images and I've tried `Path("./images").stat().st_size` and `os.path("/Users/koledavis/Documents/homework/Summer 2020/CS 1410/P7/images").st_size` and both keep showing that the size of the folder "images" is only 7250 bytes when I know that the size of the folder is over 3 million bytes. Anyone know why I'm not getting the correct number?

Comment: The `st_size` attribute of a folder is _not_ the size of all the files contained in the folder.  You'll have to add up the `st_size` attributes of all the files in the folder.

Comment: That makes sense! I used a for loop to go through every file in the folder and now I get the correct number. Thanks for the clarification!